# How can I make part of a JLabel visible under mouse movement?

Tags: java, mouse, swing

The JLabel has an image of a room. I want the mouse to act as a flashlight, and only display around the mouse the part of the JLabel/image that the mouse is hovering over, in a large circumference.

How do I make a part of the JLabel, relative to the position of the mouse, visible only under the location of the mouse?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different solutions on Stack Overflow that describe in detail how to do this:

- [Using RadialGradientPaint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15489299/531762)
- [Using Ellipse2D](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18392674/531762)
- [Using a JLayer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41927015/531762)

Personally, I think the RadialGradientPaint solution is the one best suited to your needs, since it can make it so that the edges are dimmer than the center, which better emulates the flashlight effect you are looking for.

Comment: Is it possible to get a usage example for the RadialGradientPaint?

Comment: @Charanor There is a full example on Stack Overflow at that link.

Comment: Oh I see,  I'm on the phone and the app didn't make the text blue to indicate a link. All well:)